# How can I debug failed Github Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am new to Github Actions and I am currently trying to generate .pdf files for each of my .tex files. Currently, I have taken an example from https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-action-for-latex and my .yml looks like this,

```
name: LaTeX PDF generator
on: [push]

jobs:
  build_latex:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set up Git repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Compile LaTeX document
        uses: xu-cheng/latex-action@v2
        with:
          root_file: "*.tex"
          glob_root_file: true
          
      - name: Upload PDF file
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: PDF
          path: main.pdf
```

When I build it online, I get the following error.

```
Compile C
Error:  File 'C' cannot be found from the directory '/github/workspace'.
```

I did not make any of these files/folders and I am unsure how to progress or debug this, given my action is nearly identical to the one from the example and the error is from a VM.